# 2021 FLASH content play

Tags: linux-mint, flash

since the end of flash we are unable to run flash content in any of our computers not even in web browsers, is there a way to keep running flash content on linux web browsers such as chrome, chrommium or firefox?

Answer (score 4):

On linux-mint based on ubuntu xenial or bionic, you can to install `gnash` and `browser-plugin-gnash`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnash browser-plugin-gnash
```

Comment: Seems good enough to play https://www.videogamedc.com/Pixeled_Parodies/Rise_Of_The_Mushroom_Kingdom/r1.swf